# Can I change the automatic subject prefix for `Re:`plys in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I use the web version of Outlook Mail. An e-mail's subject line is automatically prefixed with `AW:` when I reply (German: **A**nt**w**ort), which I regard as non-international and generally a bad idea.

I would like to use `Re:`, but haven't found the setting anywhere. Can I change it?